# Live Image from camera in GTK

Tags: c, image, gtk, gtk2

First: 
I am working on a dark-field microscopic tracking program. This program is old (2012), we got a new camera but this camera can´t be captured with a capture program. So I need to write a "capture program" for this camera with the SDK (Software development kit) from the company of the camera.

The tracking program is writen in C and GTK 2, so I would like to have the "capture program" in C and GTK 2 too, so I can just put the "capture program" in my tracking program. I can take a picture inside the "capture program" and show it as `gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf`.

Problem: 
After being able to take pictures I found out that the dark-field microscope is not able to let you set the focus for the camera with your eyes. So now I need to capture a "live image", video or how ever you want to call it. 
My idea was to use a timer so the camera will take a picture every second and display it as an image so the program has to delete the old image and show the new one.
But that doesn´t happen I am pretty sure that there is no problem with the camera, because it shows the first image. My guess is that the pixbuf isn´t cleared and that causes that there is no new image shown.
The "capture program" doesn´t have to stay as a C/Gtk2 program but as I am not a computer scientist I just have no idea how to get the images into the tracking program if they are different.

Code: 
I know that `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data` has a starde of `width*1` and not `width*3` that is no problem.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned short *buffer = NULL;
long imageSize = 0;

void draw_call (GtkWidget *window, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data){

    (void)event; (void)data;
    GdkPixbuf *pix;
    GtkWidget* image;
    image = gtk_image_new();

    free (buffer);
    long result = NOERR;


//camera commands had to be changed 
    result = getImageSizeFromCamera( &imageSize);

    result = SetBitsPerPixel(8);

    buffer = (unsigned short *) malloc( imageSize*2);

    result = takePicture(camera, buffer, imageSize/2, NULL, NULL);

    result = stopTakingPicture (camera);
//end of camera commands

    pix = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data ((unsigned int *) buffer, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,FALSE, 8,
               1936, 1460, 1936*1, pixbuf_free, NULL);

    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pix);


    return image;
gtk_widget_unref (pix);
}

void pixbuf_free(guchar *pixels, gpointer data)
{
    g_free(pixels) ;
    fprintf(stderr, "pixbuf data freed\n") ;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;


    // GTK

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget* image;

    image = gtk_image_new();


    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);


    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Image Viewer");

    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (Deinit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (window, "expose-event",G_CALLBACK (draw_call), NULL);


    g_timeout_add (1000, draw_call, NULL);

    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(window, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_double_buffered(window, FALSE);


    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You already have an image and you want to update the content. What about [gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-set-from-pixbuf) instead of `gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf`?  This does not make any sense for 2 reasons `return image; gtk_widget_unref (pix);`: 1) Function `data_call` has return type `void` and 2) After a `return` statement no more code is reachable. Also who should use that return value anyway?

Comment: I am not that familar with gtk2 but I would assume that you should pass the `image` pointer from `main` as user parameter to `draw_call` and update that image with the new pixbuf.

Comment: The ```gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf``` I will try. For the ```_unref (pix)``` after return I saw it in some other post and just tried it out. For the Function ```data_call``` why it´s ```void``` I didn´t know what else to use. The idea with the ```image``` pointer I will try.

Comment: Then that other code was wrong. The main purpose of `return` is to leave the current function imediately and provide a value to the caller. If you leave the function all remaining code is dead code. Also the timer handler won't know what to do with your return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

1. Your drawing function does not have correct signature to be used in `g_timer_add`. It must return a `TRUE` to keep going and it must take other parameters.
2. You have some code after returning from that function which can never bbe executed.
3. You return a pointer to `GtkImage` from timer handler wich is not correct. It must return `TRUE/FALSE`. The timer wrapper does not know what to do with such a pointer.
4. You do not update any widget yourself. I will show this in an example.
5. You create images again and again while you only need to update the existing one.

I have extended the sample for your previous question with update functionality:

```c
// build:
// gcc -o test `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -Wall -Wextra test.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t r;
  uint8_t g;
  uint8_t b;
} rgb;


int basecolour = 0;


void pixbuf_free(guchar *pixels, gpointer data)
{
  g_free(pixels) ;
  (void)data;    
  fprintf(stderr, "pixbuf data freed\n") ;
}

gboolean draw_call(gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkImage *image = (GtkImage *) user_data;
    
  size_t Width  = 1936;
  size_t Height = 1280;
  size_t Stride_rgb = Width; // Might need rounding up

  // Put raw image data from the camera in the buffer.     
  rgb *buffer_rgb = malloc(Stride_rgb * Height * sizeof(rgb));

  for (size_t x = 0; x < Width; x++)
    for (size_t y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
      // Convert 1 byte greyscale in 3 byte RGB:
      uint8_t grey = (basecolour + x+y) & 0xFF;
      buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].r = grey;
      buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].g = grey;
      buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].b = grey;
    }
    basecolour += 5;

  GdkPixbuf *pixbuf_rgb = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data((guchar*)buffer_rgb, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,FALSE, 8,
              Width, Height, Stride_rgb*3, pixbuf_free, NULL);
  gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(image, pixbuf_rgb);
  g_object_unref(pixbuf_rgb);

  return TRUE;  
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t Width  = 1936;
    size_t Height = 1280;
    size_t Stride_8 = Width;   // Might need rounding up
    size_t Stride_rgb = Width; // Might need rounding up

    //Due to lack of camera data, lets use some dummy data...
    uint8_t *buffer_8 = malloc(Stride_8*Height);
    for (size_t x = 0; x < Width; x++)
      for (size_t y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        buffer_8[Stride_8*y + x] = (x+y) & 0xFF;

    /*code to take raw image data from camera*/

    // Put raw image data from the camera in the buffer.     
    rgb *buffer_rgb = malloc(Stride_rgb * Height * sizeof(rgb));

    for (size_t x = 0; x < Width; x++)
      for (size_t y = 0; y < Height; y++)
      {
        // Convert 1 byte greyscale in 3 byte RGB:
        uint8_t grey = buffer_8[Stride_8*y + x];
        buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].r = grey;
        buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].g = grey;
        buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].b = grey;
        }

    // GTK
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (window), "test");
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf_rgb = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data((guchar*)buffer_rgb, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,FALSE, 8,
               Width, Height, Stride_rgb*3, pixbuf_free, NULL);
    GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf_rgb);
    g_object_unref(pixbuf_rgb);  

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    g_timeout_add (1000, draw_call, image);
    gtk_main();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Again, I have added some dummy code to replace your image capture part.
I have tested on Linux and it updates the image with every call of the timer handler.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is working! But I had this already working, the problem why I tought it wasn´t woking, was because the commands from the camera company were poorly writen, so I put too much information into the buffer so the picture was black. After getting your example code with the dumy data I found out what I had to change in the camera commands. Again thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The updating of the images is triggered by the `expose_event` callback that is `draw_call` in your code, for details see [How to get webcam feed to GTK window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474813/how-to-get-webcam-feed-to-gtk-window)

You know that there is tracking implemented in OpenCV ? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html

You can also code the image capturing in OpenCV

[OpenCV - Getting picture from default webcam in C/C++ - GTK Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029939/opencv-getting-picture-from-default-webcam-in-c-c-gtk-issues)

In *GUVCVIEWER* is implemented the functionality that you need and possibly you can port the source code if your camera uses the `uvc` driver https://github.com/jaswdr/guvcview/blob/master/gview_v4l2core/v4l2_core.c

Comment: Yes I know all of this but it doesn´t work because OpenCV and the other 6 capture programs that I tryed can´t use my camera. If I could just use a capture api I wouldn´t have this problem.

Comment: guvcviewer also not ? What driver kernel module uses the microscope ?

Comment: check with i.e. `dmesg`

Comment: I am building for Windows but I cheacked ```dmesg``` on a Linux PC and it says it´s using ehci-pci is that what you need?.

Comment: For Windows i do not know this. Is /dev/video0 existing ? Check if your `dmesg` output is similar to the 'Loading' section in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/webcam_setup. Important is the v4l2 stuff

Comment: I checked again but no capture program is working for me, probably because the company of the camera changed the commands how the camera is called upon. Thanks anyway. (The program is working thanks to the input from Gerhardh)